# What is the meaning of the STAGING_DIR variable in makefile

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I know this is a noob question but I couldn't find a good explanation... 
I am currently learning how to work with makefiles and I get sometimes an error like:  'STAGING_DIR not set' when running make. 
I know I can export a directory as staging dir and the warning will go away but what is the meaning of it? and what make do with it?

If it is in any documentation a link will be more then enough thanks :)

Comment: None. It has no intrinsic meaning, it's a variable that must have been used by who wrote the makefile, it's not a special make variable. It's impossible to say anything without seeing the makefile itself.

Comment: You Should share the code to see where the problem could come from.

Answer (score 2):

There is no meaning for `STAGING_DIR` built into make, but the name `STAGING_DIR` suggests the designer of the makefile intended it to be the name of a directory where some sort of intermediate files would be put.

Most likely you can assign to it the path of any directory you create where files built during the build may be placed. However, inspect of the makefile would be necessary to determine how it is used. If it is used solely for intermediate files, and not permanent files, then you can use a temporary directory and remove it when you are done building, or you might use a semi-permanent directory with the benefit of faster builds when you build incrementally. (What constitutes a temporary or semi-permanent directory is mostly a matter of convenience: You might put a temporary directory in a common path used for such things, hopefully on a disk volume with available space and good performance, possibly a directory pointed to by `$TMPDIR`. Some areas designated for temporary directories may be automatically cleaned up by the operating system at times. You might put a semi-permanent directory somewhere in your own home directory and remove it at your convenience.)

In spite of the name, `STAGING_DIR` might be used for final output files of the build, in which case using a temporary directory that is removed frequently might not be suitable. Again, inspect of the makefile is necessary to see how it is used.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from gcc etc not  make or its makefiles

"armeb-openwrt-linux-gcc: warning: environment variable 'STAGING_DIR' not defined"

Comment: This makes very little sense without more context.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35280227)